# Sketching the image of a mapping under Sinh(z)

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asks to find and sketch the image of $$ (z\in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z)<0, -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\Im(z)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}) $$ for the mapping $$w=f(z) = sinh(z)$$ I started by writing sinh(z) as  $$sinh(x)cosy+icosh(x)sin(y)$$ and looking at the boundaries of the mapping. I let $$ y=-\frac{\pi}{2}, x<0$$
which gives $$ w=-icosh(x), x<0 $$ implying $$ \Re(w) = 0, \Im(w) > 1$$ Doing the same thing for $$ y=\frac{\pi}{2}, x<0 $$ gives $$ \Re(w)=0, \Im(w)<1$$ From here I got a bit lost and had a look at the answer which was $$ (w\in\mathbb{C}: \Re(w)<0)\cup(w\in\mathbb{C}: \Re(w)=0, |\Im(w)|>1) $$The second part looks like it follows on from what I've done, but I'm having trouble seeing where the first part of the answer is coming from. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I added a diagram which illustrates detail process of mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let \begin{align}
D&=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \Re(z)<0, -\frac{\pi}{2}<\Im(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}\},\\
D_1&=\{\zeta\in\mathbb{C}: \Im(\zeta)< 0, -\frac{\pi}{2}<\Re(\zeta)<\frac{\pi}{2}\},\\
H^-&=\{\xi\in\mathbb{C}: \Im(\xi)<0\},\\
G&=\{w\in\mathbb{C}: \Re(w)<0\}
\end{align}
and consider\begin{align}
\zeta&=\varphi (z)=iz,\quad \varphi : D\to D_1,\\
\xi&=\phi(\zeta)=\sin \zeta,\quad \phi : D_1\to H^-,\\
w&=\psi(\xi)=-i\xi, \quad \psi : H^-\to G.
\end{align}

Then $$
w=\psi\circ\phi\circ\varphi (z)=\sinh (z)$$
maps $D$ onto $G$.

I have no time now, but a diagram will be added later.

Addendum: The diagram below illustrates process of mapping. The important fact is that $\xi=\sin \zeta$ maps $D_1$ onto $H^-$. 
[image]